# Git Auto Pull from one user directory to another

Tags: git, version-control, git-post-receive

I am trying to implement post-receive hook by submitting my changes from one user to be copied to the live folder owned b another user.

Here is my case:

My git repo user: **git**

My live directory user: **apache**

In my **/etc/sudoers** I wrote this:

```
git ALL=(apache) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git
```

In my post-receive hook I wrote this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "************"
echo "Post receive hook: Updating website"
echo "************"
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
        sudo -u apache git --work-tree=/var/www/testsite --git-dir=/home/git/gitrepos/testing checkout -f
done
```

The folder **/var/www/testsite** is owned by apache whereas, **/home/git/gitrepos/testing** is owned by git

When I try to push the files from my computer, I get this error:

**remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/git/gitrepos/testing'**

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not a very good idea naming your user git. Could create a lot of unwanted mixups later on. Also seems like the testing folder is not actually a git repo.

Comment: @TheGeorgeous Thanks. I can change the user later on but the problem is still there. Testing does exist and it is a bare repository. My data is pushed fine from my local computer, it is just that the post-receive hook doesn't push it to the live directory.